# Python - Format API Data for Writing to a Cloud DB

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm new to Python. I'm successfully pulling data from a web-based database using an API call I found in an SDK on Github. The data comes back fine. I'm needing to format it so I can write it back to an AWS MySQL database.

**Step 1 - the API Query:**

Here's the Python code I'm using to get the API data:

```
from infusionsoft.library import Infusionsoft
infusionsoft = Infusionsoft('APPNAME', 'API-SECRET-KEY')
table = 'Contact'
returnFields = ['Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Leadsource']
query = {'FirstName' : 'John'}
limit = 5
page = 0
rawdata = infusionsoft.DataService('query', table, limit, page, query, returnFields)
print rawdata
```

That returns a data set that looks like this:

[{'LastName': 'Marden', 'Leadsource': 'Phillips', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 602}, {'LastName': 'Macfleckno', 'Leadsource': 'Old Leads', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 722}, {'LastName': 'Donoghue', 'Leadsource': 'Phillips', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 952}, {'LastName': 'Ostman', 'Leadsource': 'Phillips', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 1046}, {'LastName': 'Tassi', 'Leadsource': 'Classifieds', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 1070}]

**Step 2 - Writing to the DB:**

I have this code working that connects to my database and writes this dummy data to a table:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(host = "HOSTNAME",user="USERNAME",passwd="PASSWORD", port=3306, db="DBNAME")
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Writers")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Writers(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
             Name VARCHAR(25))")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Jack London')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Honore de Balzac')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Lion Feuchtwanger')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Emile Zola')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('Truman Capote')")
```

That's obviously just sample code I found in a tutorial, but the connection to the DB is working, the table is being created and data is getting written.

So, how do I iterate through that data set that the API call returns and get it parsed into columns and rows suitable to write to a DB table?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The rawdata you're getting back from the API is a JSON list with five dicts.  Python has built-in support for traversing JSON objects, i.e. you don't even need to import json.

The standard *for loop* in python allows you to iterate through the list.  For each dict in the list, you'll have access to all the key/value pairs by name (e.g. writerObj["FirstName"]).

```
from pprint import pprint
rawdata = [{'LastName': 'Marden', 'Leadsource': 'Phillips', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 602}, {'LastName': 'Macfleckno', 'Leadsource': 'Old Leads', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 722}, {'LastName': 'Donoghue', 'Leadsource': 'Phillips', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 952}, {'LastName': 'Ostman', 'Leadsource': 'Phillips', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 1046}, {'LastName': 'Tassi', 'Leadsource': 'Classifieds', 'Email': 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': 1070}]
for writerObj in rawdata:
#    pprint(writerObj)
#    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('" + writerObj["FirstName"] + ' ' + writerObj["LastName"] + "')")
    pprint("INSERT INTO Writers(Name) VALUES('" + writerObj["FirstName"] + ' ' + writerObj["LastName"] + "')")
```

The pprint library is simply to print out the text to the screen.  The commented out line "cur.execute(..." is what you'll call within your code that interfaces with the database.